# TypeError: data.map is not a function in reactjs while loading photos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried to create an image search application using unsplash api but it shows the error `TypeError: data.map is not a function`. It was working fine till last night but now it suddenly shows this error. It initially loaded the page with the images but it started showing this error when I searched for moon and went to last page. I then refreshed the page and it displays the images again but as soon as I did per_page items from 5 to 9 then it shows the error again and now it''s continously showing the error. Is it a problem with the api? but even if it was the api, it should show a blank page because I did `photos: []` in the try catch block in the api call method but instead it shows the error. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. Can someone help me please

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";
import List from "./List";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

const LOAD_STATE = {
  SUCCESS: "SUCCESS",
  ERROR: "ERROR",
  LOADING: "LOADING"
};

const appId = "N1ZIgf1m1v9gZJhledpAOTXqS8HqL2DuiEyXZI9Uhsk";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.fetchPhotos = this.fetchPhotos.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      photos: [],
      totalPhotos: 0,
      perPage: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
      loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING,
      search: ""
    };
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPhotos(this.state.currentPage);
  }

  fetchPhotos(page = 1) {
    var self = this;
    const { search, perPage } = this.state;
    const url1 = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos?page=${page}&client_id=${appId}`;
    const url2 =
      `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${page}&query=` +
      search +
      "&client_id=" +
      appId;
    const url = search ? url2 : url1;

    if (search) {
      const options = {
        params: {
          page: page,
          per_page: perPage,
          order_by: "popularity"
        }
      };

      this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
      axios
        .get(url, options)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(typeof response.data);
          let photos;
          try {
            photos = response.data.results;
          } catch {
            photos = [];
          }
          this.setState({
            photos,
            totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
            currentPage: page,
            loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
        });
    } else {
      const options = {
        params: {
          client_id: appId,
          page: page,
          per_page: perPage,
          order_by: "popularity"
        }
      };

      this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
      axios
        .get(url, options)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(typeof response.data);
          let photos;
          try {
            photos = response.data;
          } catch {
            photos = [];
          }
          self.setState({
            photos,
            totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
            currentPage: page,
            loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
        });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="search"
          placeholder="Enter query"
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={() => this.fetchPhotos(1)}
          className="button"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        <Pagination
          current={this.state.currentPage}
          total={this.state.totalPhotos}
          perPage={this.state.perPage}
          onPageChanged={this.fetchPhotos.bind(this)}
        />
        {this.state.loadState === LOAD_STATE.LOADING ? (
          <div className="loader" />
        ) : (
          <List data={this.state.photos} />
        )}
        <Pagination
          current={this.state.currentPage}
          total={this.state.totalPhotos}
          perPage={this.state.perPage}
          onPageChanged={this.fetchPhotos.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

List.js

```
import React from "react";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";
const List = ({ data }) => {
  var items = data.map(photo => <ListItem key={photo.id} photo={photo} />); //error here
  return <div className="grid">{items}</div>;
};

export default List;
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine in sandbox.

Comment: is it? did you search for moon and go to the last page? or did perpage items to 9 or any other number? it's not doing anything for me here @brijesh-pant

Comment: just try to click on many page numbers you can and you will see an error I think. also their documentation page is just giving me two curly braces now https://unsplash.com/documentation#error-messages are their server down?

Comment: okay I see the error on page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem that you are facing, the issue is when there is empty data from the API response the photos variable stays like `photos = {}` where in expected is `photos = []`, which you did in `catch` block but it never goes to catch block because having empty data is not error, also I have solved your issue here [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-bush-v6dht?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: your demo isn't showing any photos. the page is blank with only the search bar

Comment: Yes because if you check response currently it is having empty data, once response will have some data inside response.data, it will start to show images.

Comment: so it's the problem with the api then?

Comment: Yeah before addition of my code there was problem in our code as we did not handle empty data condition, as now we have handled empty data condition it will work in any case, currently it is issue in API.

Comment: okay thanks.. hopefully it will work when the api is working again.. i wonder why changing per items to 9 also was showing the same problem

Comment: That is again related to API stuff maybe some code missing to handle that :)

Comment: when I change the page per item to 5 then it is loading the images in the initial load @Pritesh why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218872/discussion-between-pritesh-and-gonnabefireifnohelp).